# ComponentScan and import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan can not be resolved as a type

Tags: spring, hibernate, maven

I have a problem with my project in Spring. Firstly I couldn't run it on the server but after downloading all resources again it started.

But now I have some imports which Spring can not see 
For example:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan can not be resolved as a type.
```

and autwired value

```
@ComponentScan  can not be resolved as a type.
```

Because of that hibernate is not creating tables in my database ( I think so )

Also two configuration classes have some errors:

The hierarchy of the type Spring4Initializer is inconsistent
SpringSecurityInitializer

```
public class Spring4Initializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { Spring4Configuration.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }

    @Override
    protected Filter[] getServletFilters() {
        CharacterEncodingFilter characterEncodingFilter = new CharacterEncodingFilter();
        characterEncodingFilter.setEncoding("UTF-8");
        characterEncodingFilter.setForceEncoding(true);
        return new Filter[] { characterEncodingFilter };
    }
}
```

SpringSecurityInitializer Multiple markers at this line
    - The type org.springframework.web.WebApplicationInitializer cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from 
     required .class files

```
import org.springframework.security.web.context.AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer;

public class SpringSecurityInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {

}
```

I've tried maven clean and maven build

```
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for pl.dmcs:eschool:war:1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.(groupId:artifactId:type:classifier)' must be unique: org.springframework:spring-context:jar -> version ${org.springframework-version} vs 4.3.7.RELEASE @ line 74, column 17
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.(groupId:artifactId:type:classifier)' must be unique: com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar -> version 2.8.8 vs 2.8.3 @ line 157, column 15
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.(groupId:artifactId:type:classifier)' must be unique: javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar -> version ${servlet-api-version} vs 2.5 @ line 254, column 15
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.(groupId:artifactId:type:classifier)' must be unique: org.springframework:spring-context:jar -> version ${org.springframework-version} vs 3.0.5.RELEASE @ line 271, column 14
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING] 
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building E-School 1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ eschool ---
[INFO] Deleting C:\Users\Piotr\Desktop\E-School\target
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Does anyone know what should I do with it to make hibernate working?
In Outline tree my function GetHibernateProperites() is marked as red

Answer (score 0):

Have you included the spring-context in your maven  dependencies? I think you are missing that dependency.

Comment: can i see your pom file? and you are using mvn clean install command right ?

Comment: you are having multiple spring-context dependency in your pom file try to remove them and apply "mvn clean install"

Comment: you have to call "mvn clean install" on the directory containing this pom file. so what is the result of this command ? does it succeed ?

Comment: may be you need to clean your project what ide are you using ?

Comment: I've deleted whole project and import it one more time. Cleaned maven, installed maven. And now it works. (don't know why though...) :)